# Struggling with connection to the database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, connection-string

I am trying to call a stored procedure and get **could not find stored procedure**.

I tried with command text and no stored procedure and i got could not find table name.

I have used this connection string and method of calling stored proc's in another project and it has worked.

I even copied methods from my other project that do work, and got could not find stored procedure, with the same connection string and methods. 
So it has to be something in this project.

Could it be the DB is blocking my requests or something like that?

I have used this method of calling stored procedures for the last 3 years and with this one i am completely stuck.

```
string conString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["connectionStrings"];

public void ClaimPartAcceptedSet(int PartId, bool Accepted)
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(conString);
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd1.CommandText = "AP_QuotePartsAcceptedUpdate"; 
    cmd1.ComandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartId", PartId);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Accepted", Accepted);

    cmd1.Connection = sqlConnection1;
    try
    {
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
         sqlConnection1.Close();
    }

 }
```

Web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="connectionStrings" value="data source=DEV-JHB1-1234; Initial Catalog=CarPartsAP; User Id=web_user; Password=Password;" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: It may connect to wrong database. Check the connection string. Also try to  use `dbo.AP_QuotePartsAcceptedUpdate` or whatever schema the proc is in. And use `using` statements when working with those objects.

Comment: Don't you need to specify the connection on your SqlCommand?

Comment: @mstaessen, don't you see using a connection?

Comment: I mean
    var command = new SqlCommand("AP_QuotePartsAcceptedUpdate", connection) {
    ComandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
}

Comment: @mstaessen, it just one of the overrides of the function...doesn't matter if you pass connection through constructor or explicitly assign it.

Comment: Oh, it was assigned. Did indeed look over it :(

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri i have tried with the schema as well, dbo.AP_QuotePartsAcceptedUpdate. will try with the using statments. but as mentioned iv done it this way for 3 years without error. Is it not some database setting or something i am missing?

Comment: @Pomster, no it should work if you have properly specified schema, have rights, have correct connection string, procedure exists in database.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri How do i ensure its connecting to the right database?

Comment: @Pomster, do a breakpoint on  `qlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(conString);` and see what value is in `conString`.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Great thanks, the initial catalog is different, so it is pointing to a different database.

This project must have a second connection string declared somewhere.

Wow can't believe i wasted half my day on this.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Try connecting using SQL Server Management Studio using same credentials and call the Stored Procedure as you would in the code.

This will at least verify that the credentials are still valid and if the Stored Procedure is valid. Also try adding the Schema in which the Stored Procedure is residing:

```
cmd1.CommandText = "dbo.AP_QuotePartsAcceptedUpdate"
```

**--update--**

Use a SQL Profiler to see what exactly is being called on the SQL Server. Compare this with the call from the Application which you said that did work.

Comment: He is getting `could not find stored procedure.` so he has no problem with connection. He has problem probably with connection to incorrect database.

Comment: It verifies if the logged in user has rights to the stored procedure and/or it even exists?

Comment: @RalfdeKleine I could login to sql management studio and run the proc successfully. I have tried added dbo schema in the Command Text with no difference made.

Comment: Added a step to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @GiorgiNakeuri, Answer in his comments.

Adopting the project i did not notice a **duplicate connection string deceleration**.
Break pointing on SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(conString); i noticed the **initial catalog pointing to a different database** to the one i was trying to access.